# Converting number to DateTime in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I have data imported from a CSV in R. The DateTime is in the excel format (i.e., 44410.095193, 44410.095203, etc).

Here is the dupt from a small portion of my data:

```
> dput(tail(raw.data[,1]))
structure(list(DateTime = c(44410.095193, 44410.095203, 44410.095215, 
44410.095227, 44410.095238, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002048fb61ef0>)
```

I've found that there are a couple of easy ways to convert this to a different format (i.e., 2021-08-02 02:17:04, 2021-08-02 02:17:05, etc) by using `XLDateToPOSIXct` from the `DescTools` package and `convertToDateTime` form the `openxlsx` package on the desktop version of R.

However, these functions don't work in the Jupyter Notebook version of R. I've tried to install the packages listed above in the Jupyter Notebook, but afterwards I always get an error saying:

```
#for the openxlsx package
Error in convertToDateTime(raw.data$DateTime): could not find function "convertToDateTime"
Traceback:

#for the DescTools package
Error in XLDateToPOSIXct(raw.data$DateTime): could not find function "XLDateToPOSIXct"
Traceback:
```

I am thinking there must be another way to do the conversions. I've tried the `as.Date` and `as.POSIXct` functions, but these aren't giving me all the data I need (just the date and not the time) or is incorrect (all years are 1899).

What are some functions that would work in Jupyter Notebook that would convert the numeric version of a DateTime to a an actual date/time (e.g., 2021-08-02 02:17:05)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **base R** solution that should work in your notebook. The second `as.POSIXct` enables the time part. Make sure that your data.frame dates are `numeric`.

```
dat <- c(44410.095193, 44410.095203, 44410.095215, 44410.095227, 44410.095238, NA)

class(dat)
[1] "numeric"

as.POSIXct( as.Date( dat, origin="1899-12-30" ) )
[1] "2021-08-02 04:17:04 CEST" "2021-08-02 04:17:05 CEST"
[3] "2021-08-02 04:17:06 CEST" "2021-08-02 04:17:07 CEST"
[5] "2021-08-02 04:17:08 CEST" NA
```